# how to mix javascript js file(script embedded with php) and php code in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

if my hello.js is like this

```
function jst()
{
var i = 0 ;
i = <?php echo 35; ?>
alert( i );
}
```

**what i really want in netbeans is to interpret that .js file through php interpreter without changing my extension of hello.js to hello.php** or in other words i dont wan to change extension of my file from js . the reason behind this is Because netbean provide special support(i.e editing, coloring of text etc) for files with .js extension .

this is how i am including file in index.php

```
<script>
 <?php include 'hello.php'?>;
</script>
```

code is working fine but i want to use hello.js instead hello.php in **netbeans** like as shown in following snippet

```
<script src="hello.js"></script>
```

what should i do?? how professional websites handle this issue??

*.js
http://s13.postimg.org/vl6vo4fif/image.png

*.php
http://s21.postimg.org/t7tuk42l3/after.png
every thing has converted to plain text after changing extension

Comment: Did you read my answer. PHP is server side JS is Client side. You can use `<script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>. Why not ? But php inside hello.js is now wrong , because it's handled on the client side , no server can parse the content of hello.js !!!

Comment: k thanks for replying

Comment: but the problem is how i should isolate these two things in two seperate php and js file.   i uploaded the images of before and after changing file extensions

Comment: It seems you really did not read my answer :( . I can not see `<script type="text/javascript">` above your `dragger = function` . Look at my updated answer at the top.

Comment: sorry for responding late. . . .and thanks for ur detailed reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do as the most used way, `via parameter`

hello.js

```
function jst(alertMe)
{
alert( alertMe );
}
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>jsFileTest</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       var alertMe = <?php echo 35; ?> ;
     </script>
    </head>       
<body>

<button onclick="jst(alertMe)">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Develop your `js` within your `php` file.**
If everything works as expected then you can outsource everything as a separate file `.js`

But remember : php is parsed and interpreted on server side . So **everything** outside `php tags` is **completely ignored**.  Therefore :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.js"></script>
```

is pure html and will be ignored. On server side `php` knows nothing about the existence of these `.js` file and it will not load and parse it. **But this is required if you want `php` also interpret this file too.**

**If you want to include it with a `php` file, you can do it like**

Put `<script type="text/javascript">` at the beginning. code completion starts again.

**jsFile.php**

[image]

**index2.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>jsFileTest</title>
     <?php
       include_once 'jsFile.php';
     ?>   
    </head>       
<body>
<?php
 echo "myID = ".$myId."<br>";
?>   
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Running :

[image]

But now we come to the important part.

Look at the html output source :

```
<html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>jsFileTest</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
 alert("Hi from jsFile.php");
}
</script>

    </head>       
<body>
myID = idontknow<br>   
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see , javascript ( `function myFuntion()` ) is inserted directly in the html output. That is exactly what does not happen with

```
<title>jsFileTest</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.js"></script>
```

---

---

You can not use `src="jsFile.php"`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.php"></script>
```

After the parsing is finished the content is sent to the client. From this moment it is useless to even try to parse embedded php code in javascript. (the server is no longer involved , has already done its work)

IE detects an error (Status Line). when you double-click this

[image]

Error window pops up

[image]

the browser expects valid javascript code and this

```
$myId = "idontknow";
```

is not a valid JS code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable the PHP to read JS files. Do this:
Open your httpd.conf (Apache configuration file) and find this line:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

And add the extension, modifying this line to:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .js
```

You can even add CSS files too.

Answer (score 0):

put this in customJs.php

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php ob_end_clean(); ?>
    alert('aaaa');
<?php ob_start(); ?>
</script>
<?php ob_end_clean(); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you explain what this does and how it solves the OPs problem?